# On which software can I simulate landmass collisions?

Tags: plate-tectonics, land-surface, crust, simulation

Such as in 3D simulations of vehicule crashes but this time with huge rocks or bodies of water (continental plates). I need to be able to set the properties of the material (density, size etc) and see what happens according to physic laws.